# is it possible to open files with a custom script by default?

Tags: 14.04, scripts, default-programs

I've created some scripts to run google chrome and other applications on ubuntu 14.04 using certain arguments. The problem is that when the program is executed for instance by double clicking a .html file in the file manager the default version of google chrome is executed, not as specified in my script.
I tried setting the custom script as the default command to open that type of file but then the program is run without opening the particular file, adding %u, %f to the script didn't help either.
This is the one I use with google chrome for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset -dpms
google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1 --password-store=basic --window-position=318,0
tvt=$(pgrep -c "tvtime")
vlc=$(pgrep -c "vlc")
if [ "$tvt" -eq 0 ] && [ "$vlc" -eq 0 ] ; then
  xset dpms 0 600 0
fi
```

Comment: Tried specifying full path to the chrome you want inside the script ?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried creating a .desktop file for the script but it still does not open the particular file.

Answer (score 0):

When you double click on your script, it'll run your script.  It'll use the shebang specified interpreter to run your script.

If you want your script to perform an operation such as opening and HTML file you would have to specify in your script which browser program by name to call.

Your script won't come be activated by double clicking on a file other than your script.  If you double click on an HTML file this will open the file with the default application that you have setup for that type of file.

You can set or change the default application in a number of ways.  You can do it via GUI by running `System-Settings`  -> (click) `Default Applications`, then choose your browser from the drop down `Web` options.

You can also configure which program is called by default when clicked by right clicking on it from your file browser, then click `Properties`, then click the `Open with` tab and select your preference there.

Alternatively you can also edit the `/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list` which will effect system-wide users or `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` which will effect per-user changes.

Comment: I can get the script to be executed by double clicking on a file (by using the 'custom command' option of the default applications program) but then the particular file is not opened, only the application. For instance google chrome is launched showing the homepage, not the .html file I double clicked on.

Comment: @asta666 You are having a problem with your script.  You would to add lines from the script to your question so that we can identify exactly what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I've included one of the scripts.